# Swiper thumbnail slider behaving odd when centeredSlides is set to false

Tags: jquery, css, thumbnails, swiper.js

I have two sliders: a main slider on the left side and a thumbnail-slider acting as the thumbnail-view for the main slider. The thumbnail-slider, however, is not behaving correctly: Around the sixth or seventh slide, the thumbnail-slider picks the thumbnail before the current one, instead of taking the next, and after that it stays buggy.

I tried setting the `centeredSlides` option to `true`. The thumbnail-slider is then behaving correctly. However, I need `centeredSlides` to be `false` and the currently active thumbnail-slide has to be the top one.

You probably get my point better with a script, so here goes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var productSlider = new Swiper('.product-slider', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 10
  });
  var productThumbs = new Swiper('.product-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 5,
    centeredSlides: false,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    touchRatio: 0.2,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    direction: 'vertical'
  });
  productSlider.params.control = productThumbs;
  productThumbs.params.control = productSlider;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.product-slider {
  height: 430px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ECECEC;
 }
 
.product-slider .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-thumbs {
  height: 430px;
}

.product-thumbs .swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
  border: solid 2px #ECECEC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="swiper-container product-slider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="swiper-container product-thumbs">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I just don't know, if it can be done better. First, I set the `centeredSlides` option to true, like here:

```
var productThumbs = new Swiper('.product-thumbs', {
  spaceBetween: 5,
  centeredSlides: true, // changed this from false to true
  slidesPerView: 4,
  touchRatio: 0.2,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  direction: 'vertical'
});
```

And then I give the `.swiper-wrapper` class a negative margin-top, like so:

```
.product-thumbs .swiper-wrapper {
  margin-top: calc(-100% + 5px); /* Added this... adjust to your needs */
}
```

And now the slider is working. The negative margin given to .swiper-wrapper depends on your other styles, it seems. The margins for my project are correct (so that the topmost thumbnail image is lined up with the main sliders top edge), in the following example you can play around with the margin-top value!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var productSlider = new Swiper('.product-slider', {
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 10
  });
  var productThumbs = new Swiper('.product-thumbs', {
    spaceBetween: 5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    touchRatio: 0.2,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    direction: 'vertical'
  });
  productSlider.params.control = productThumbs;
  productThumbs.params.control = productSlider;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.product-slider {
  height: 430px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ECECEC;
 }
 
.product-slider .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-thumbs {
  height: 430px;
}

/* Play around with this. Maybe your project does not use a vertical
thumbnail slider, but instead a horizontal one. You'd have to change the
margin-left values for this */
.product-thumbs .swiper-wrapper {
  margin-top: calc(-100% + 5px);
}

.product-thumbs .swiper-slide {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
  border: solid 2px #ECECEC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="swiper-container product-slider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/10">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="swiper-container product-thumbs">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/90/90/nature/10">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'width' to your thumbs gallery to solve the problem:

```
var datesSwiper = new Swiper('[data-name="history-years"]', {
    width: 100,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
    slideActiveClass: 'history__year_active'
});
```